# How to keep received image from the socket in the buffer

Tags: python, sockets, io

I am working on the project that receives an image from a remote computer through sockets. As I don`t know what is going to be the size of the image I am receiving the image chunk by chunk, and saving to `io.BytesIO()`

```
    def imgdisplayer():
        nonlocal conn, display
        with io.BytesIO() as f:
            while True:
                bytes = conn.recv(1024)
                if not bytes: break
                f.write(bytes)
            imgobj = pickle.loads(f)
```

But my code is not working, I guess I have a misuderstanding of the `io.BytesIO`
The error being risen here is that:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'
```

Can someone help on how I can fix the problem or suggest another way to do the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BytesIO` is a file-like object. You should use the `getvalue()` method if you need its value:

```
imgobj = pickle.loads(f.getvalue())
```